# Moving SKNode by One Tile From Its Current Position

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit, sktilemapnode

I'm playing with the tile editor, with which I've created a simple, somewhat large map like the following.  The tile size is 64 x 64.  And the map size is 58 x 32.

[image]

And I want to know the current position of the game character.  Let me call it player (as `SKNode`).  I want to know this guy's current position so that I can find out whether any of its adjascent tile is NOT an obstacle.  The following lines of code gives me (7, -3).

```
background = self.childNode(withName: "World") as! SKTileMapNode
let position = background.convert(player.position, from: player)
let column = background.tileColumnIndex(fromPosition: position)
let row = background.tileRowIndex(fromPosition: position)
print(column, row)
```

, which suggests that these coordinates point to the center of the camera, indicated by the red circle.  The following gives me (10, 2).

```
let position = background.convert(player.position, from: self)
let column = background.tileColumnIndex(fromPosition: position)
let row = background.tileRowIndex(fromPosition: position)
```

That's the position from the bottom-left corner.

Now, if I want to move the game character up by 1 tile, writing...

```
let position = background.convert(player.position, from: player)
let column = background.tileColumnIndex(fromPosition: position)
let row = background.tileRowIndex(fromPosition: position)
let destination = background.centerOfTile(atColumn: column, row: row + 1)
let action = SKAction.move(to: destination, duration: 1)
player.run(action)
```

, the game character will go missing in action, disappearing from the face of the map.  So how can I move the node by one tile?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
    let currentPlayerPosition = background.convert(player.position, from: player)
    let column = background.tileColumnIndex(fromPosition: currentPlayerPosition)
    let row = background.tileRowIndex(fromPosition: currentPlayerPosition)
    let destination = background.centerOfTile(atColumn: column, row: row + 1)

    // the new line I added
    let newPlayerPosition = background.convert(destination, to: player)

    let action = SKAction.move(to: newPlayerPosition, duration: 1)
    player.run(action)
```

Comment: No.  The node will disappear from the face of the map.

Comment: Maybe a simple suggestion, but try printing the actual CGPoints of the player's current and desired position. If the player is just moving off the map, then the simplest idea that comes to mind is that the CGPoints are off the map as well.